# A property on $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

I would like to know, why:

If $X$ is a subspace of $ L^p(G)$ such that $\overline{X}\neq L^p(G)$, $\,$ then there exists $g\in L^q(G)$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ such that
$$\int_Gf(x)\,g(x)\,dx=0; \quad \forall f\in \overline{X}.$$
Where $G$ is a locally compact group with Haar measure $dx$.

Comment: Why can't we choose $g=0$?  What is $G$?

Comment: You probably want $g \ne 0$ and I think you also want $X$ to be a subspace of $L^p(G)$, whose closure is not the whole of $X$ (almost equivalently take $X$ to be a proper closed subspace of $L^p(G)$.

Comment: Yes $X$ is a subspace of $L^p(G)$.

Comment: Isn't it a consequence of $i \overline{X} = {X}^{\perp  \perp }$ ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement , which is itself a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\overline{X}$ is a proper closed subspace of the Banach space $L^p(G)$, the quotient space $L^p(G)/\overline{X}$ is a nonzero Banach space. So there is some nonzero linear functional $\phi$ on $L^p(G)/\overline{X}$, whose composition with the quotient map is a nonzero linear functional on $L^p(G)$ that vanishes on $\overline{X}$. Finally that functional corresponds to some $g\in L^q(G)$ since $L^q$ is the dual of $L^p$.

Comment: @ 1830rbc03 , the linear functional $\phi$ is from $L^p(G)/\overline{X}$ to ?

Comment: @Z.Alfata To $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, whichever you are considering. That's Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Hahn Banach: It allows the extension of bounded linear functionals defined on a subspace of some vector space to the whole space. How can we apply it directly to our case?

Comment: @Z.Alfata Hahn-Banach implies that any nonzero Banach space has a nonzero functional on it: pick a $1$-dimensional subspace, there is certainly a nonzero functional, and then extend it to the whole space. For details see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229175/how-hahn-banach-theorem-implies-that-the-dual-space-is-non-trivial/2229185